# How can i call a file in a function in c

Tags: c

I have created a file in binary reading mode:

```
FILE *fd1 = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
if(fd1 == NULL){
    printf("Cannot find file.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

This file contains elements that are saved in the struct:

```
typedef struct{
    char c;     
    int count; 
}run;
```

The question is, how can a call a file in a function? For example, i want to create a funtion that prints the elements of the file:

```
void print_elements( /* parameters */ );
```

What should the parameters be to call the file fd1, in the main class and in the function ?.

Comment: Do you mean [_reading_](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm) a file, not _calling_ it?

Comment: Yes the parameters is the problem

Comment: `void print_elements(FILE* f) { ... }`

Comment: What is the `print_elements` function supposed to do? To read from the file *and* display its contents? Or to receive the already read contents and just display it?

Comment: Recieve the already read contents and display it. This funtion will help me with the entire algorythm

Comment: Then you supposedly have an array of `run` structure somewhere? Pass a pointer to the first element, and the number of valid elements in the array.

Comment: Or maybe a linked list containing the structure?

Comment: I suggest you split the work to simpler tasks as functions: 1) A function to open the file given his path 2) A function to read the next item from the file 3) A function to print a read item 3) A function to close the file 4) A function to move to an arbitrary position on an item (considering the file as an array of items.   Almost all those task a trivial to implement in C. I suggest you either make it yourself and if needed, open other question on StackOverflow for each task you have difficulties to implement.